# Scheduling 2 Macros

Tags: vba, excel

*(edit: On subsequent edit, the poster declared that the problem had been solved and had been due to a spelling error then deleted the entire question text. Text restored with addition of this comment)*

---

I have 2 macros that i need to scheduled:

Macro1 "GetData" - this needs to run every 35mins - to retrieve data from my DB.
Macro2 "RefreshData" - this needs to run every 1min after GetData is complete - to update my data.

I have tried:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:35:10"), "GetData"
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "RefreshData"

End Sub
```

However, i am presented with:

"Cannot run the macro "c:\document and settings\alex\desktop\data.xlsm'!GetData'/ The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macro's may be disabled"

```
Sub GetData ()

'' GetData ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, data As Worksheet

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set data = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\alex\Desktop\source.XLS"). _
    Worksheets("Report 1")

Sheets("Report 1").Select
Set Rng = Sheets("Report 1").Range("A2:K350")
Selection.Copy

sh1.Activate
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

portfolioName.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub

Sub RefreshData()

MsgBox ("-- Update every 1min --")

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

-- Update -------

I have now created a separate GetData module:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:35:10"), "GetData"
'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "RefreshData"

End Sub

Public Sub GetData()
'' GetData ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
....
....
End Sub
```

Still receive same error..

-- Update------

Ok, within Sheet1 i have:

```
Public Sub workbook_open()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:35:10"), "GetData"
'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "RefreshData"

End Sub
```

I have now Insert > Module and renamed the module to GetData

Within that GetData module i have:

```
Public Sub GetData()
'' GetData ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
....
....
End Sub
```

Any comments welcome

Comment: You're going to need to leave some part of your question in the question. You can't edit away the whole thing. People can't answer "Thanks for the suggestions guys, it was a spelling error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnTime requires the referenced macro to be in a standard module. The sub must also be public, which is default for a module. Insert a module, and move GetData and RefreshData into it.

Comment: New module added, still same issue

Comment: Issue was i had incorrectly titled a module., school boy error